# File no longer available when trying to edit in vim via <()

Tags: shell, vim

When working with mercurial, I frequently do things like

```
vim <(hg cat -r 42 somefile)
```

However, if I try this with a file larger than several hundred lines, I get a Read Error in vim, and only the first couple of hundred lines are included. If I use gvim instead of vim, I get an error like

```
E211: FIle "/proc/3546/fd/63" no longer available
```

Isn't this supposed to work? I don't know if it's relevant, but I've tried both in bash and zsh, with the same result, and I also tried

```
cat <(hg cat -r 42 somefile)
```

which prints the entire file as I would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are pipes, not regular files. It goes away when `vim` closes the file descriptor. You could do:

```
hg cat -r 42 somefile | vim -
```

(there `vim` is told it may not be a regular file so behaves accordingly. Use `vim -R -` or `view -` if you don't want `vim` to complain that the data has not been saved on exit).

Or with `zsh`, using a temporary file:

```
vim =(hg cat -r 42 somefile)
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, though I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "It goes away when `vim` closes the file descriptor." The read error happens as I try to open the file. Also, just to clarify, I know I can't edit the file in this way, I just want to load it into vim to have a look around.

Comment: If it closes is, the next attempt to open it will fail. Typically, when you run gvim, gvim forks a process and probably does so after closing most fds in an attempt to disconnect from the terminal.

Comment: Ah, ok. Though the same happens when I try to open the file in vim in the terminal. And why does it manage to read part of the file? (I'm not trying to be difficult, I'm just curious about these things.)

Comment: @Tor, I can't reproduce it with `vim <(seq 100000)` for instance. In any case, I wouldn't expect a _read_ error. What's the exact error you're getting? Note that if anything (like things that try to detect file type or get information from the file) called by autocmds open and read the pipe, what they read will be missing within vim.

Comment: When I open in vim in the terminal, the bottom line says for example "/proc/self/fd/11" [fifo/socket][READ ERRORS][dos] 238L, 8192C. The file is actually 2935 lines. It seems very random, though. It happens to some files which are 2500 lines, while some files at 3000 lines are fine. But whenever there is a read error, it reads 8192 characters.

Comment: Tested a few more things. `vim <(seq 10000000)` works just fine for me as well. And `vim <(cat somefile)` gives the same error and number of characters with the same files as using `hg cat -r`.

Comment: Sorry to be nagging you, but do you have any further insight into this? Your solution with the temporary file in zsh works perfectly, but it's really bugging me that I don't understand the original problem.

Comment: @Tor, Possibly things that are done via your `.vimrc` or `autocmd`s cause it (like things done upon detection of file type). I would run `vim` under `strace -ff -o some-file` with the `verbose` option set to a high value to check at which point the file is being closed.